# std::string -> execvp etc

Tags: c++, exec

I just found an elusive bug in a program and it turned out to be because with optimization enabled, in something like the following sometimes the std::string is destroyed before processDocument() got the text out of it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <spawn.h>
#include <string>
static void processDocument(const char* text) {
        const char* const argv[] = {
                "echo",
                text,
                NULL,
        };
        pid_t p;
        posix_spawnp(&p, "echo", NULL, NULL, (char**) argv, environ);
}
static int mark = 'A';
static void createDocument() {
        const char* vc;
        std::string v = "ABCKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK42";
        ++mark;
        v[0] = mark;
        vc = v.c_str();
        processDocument(vc);
}
int main() {
        createDocument();
        createDocument();
        return(0);
}
```

How do I safely convert a std::string to a char* for use in execvp, posix_spawnp etc ?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107305/sharing-data-across-processes-on-linux

Comment: The program that you share should not behave the way you describe. Have you ever seen **that exact program** produce incorrect results?

Comment: Whether in this program or your original program, what behavior did you see that led you believe "the std::string is destroyed before processDocument() got the text out of it"?

Comment: >Have you ever seen that exact program produce incorrect results?

No. As soon as I trim it down, the problem mysteriously vanishes.

>Whether in this program or your original program, what behavior did you see that led you believe "the std::string is destroyed before processDocument() got the text out of it"

The contents stored in the argv[1], starting 100 characters in or so will be garbled.

Comment: The original program can be found at http://svn.nomike.com/playground/trunk/5D/ the call is in GUI/GTKREPL.cc around line 908, GTKLATEXGenerator_enqueue will get the char* and call the external program with it. Note that there's a workaround in place now, search that file for /* otherwise will have memory corruption */

Comment: I tried to set resultString = "$ \\mathrm{'}\\left(\\mathrm{let\\:}\\mathrm{x}\\mathrm{\\::=\\:}\\mathrm{5}\\mathrm{\\:in\\:}\\‌​‌​mathrm{2}\\mathrm{\\cdot }\\mathrm{x} \\right) $" and then nodeText = resultString.c_str() just before I called GTKLATEXGenerator_enqueue() so it's (probably) not something before that. In this case, it will be broken just before the end: $ \mathrm{'}\left(\mathrm{let\:}\mathrm{x}\mathrm{\::=\:}\mathrm{5}\mathrm{\:in\:}\‌​‌​mathrm{2}\mathrm{\cdot }\mathrm{x} \r� <-- tried again with what is in SVN (with the line with /* c... */ mentio. a. changed),still happens.

Answer (score 1):

I found out why it really was (here the actual minimal testcase):

```
std::string resultString;
const char* nodeText;
const char* altText;
resultString = "......whatever1.";
nodeText = resultString.c_str();
resultString = ".....whatever2..";
altText = resultString.c_str();
printf("%s\n", nodeText); // garbage
```

Bad idea.